# Can't understand why Python won't import the file

Tags: python

I have the following project structure:

```
├── my_app
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── my_pkg
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── utils.py
    │   ├── app.py
    ├── other_pkg...
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── ...
    ├── ...
```

I want in the `my_app/my_pkg/app.py` to import `utils`. I want to call that Python file from anywhere. For example, I want to be in `my_app` and run `python my_pkg/app.py`.

Adding the following line in `app.py` throws the exception `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named my_app`:

```
from my_app.my_pkg import utils
```

I know I can add the path to sys.path but I don't want to do that. I don't understand why Python can't consider the above project structure as a package and just import the files. I find it really ugly to add paths to sys to get Python to find the files!

Any suggestions?

Comment: What if you do `from . import utils`?

Comment: `from my_app.my_pkg` means that `my_pkg` is a subdirectory of `my_app`.

Comment: Sorry my_pkg is a subdir

Comment: Doing `from . import utils` says `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`

Comment: @drum that wouldn't work unless you ran it with `python -m my_pkg.app`.

Comment: Sorry, but that's just not how Python works.  You are not using `app.py` as a package.  You are using it as an application, and that's the problem.  If you had imported `app` through the `my_pkg` package, it would work.  Given that structure, you absolutely need to modify `sys.path` to tell Python where to find your files.

Comment: @TimRoberts there's no need to modify `sys.path`. Just run it as a module and use relative imports.

Comment: "I know I can add the path to sys.path but I don't want to do that." - too bad; `sys.path` **is how Python decides** where to look for absolute imports. If you don't want that, use a relative import instead. "I don't understand why Python can't consider the above project structure as a package and just import the files." Using absolute import, by defintion, is explicitly disregarding any package structure. If you want to treat the project structure as a package, that is what relative import is for.

Comment: `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package` - yes; *relative* import on the other hand requires Python to know *where the top level of the package is*; it **does not** infer this from filesystem structure - the leading `.` in a relative import represent **package hierarchy** levels, **not** directories.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
import my_pkg.utils
```

or

```
import sys
sys.path.append("./')

import my_pkg.utils
```